# How to generate random math expression trees with sympy?

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I am scouring the web but I cannot find how to generate random math expressions with sympy. Is it even possible?

I would like to build an expression tree by randomly selecting functions (product, sum, cosine...) and symbols from a set of predefined functions and symbols.
For instance, given the set [+,.] of sum and product and the symbols [x,y] I'd like to generate expressions such as x+y, (x+y).x, y+(x.x+y)+x etc, controlling parameters as the tree depth, width and the number of nodes.

Any hints?

Comment: I doubt if anyone else has tried to do this, so a web search is not going to help.  However generating "random" strings/sentences is likely to be more common.  Those can then be 'parsed' to make sympy expressions.  Another approach is to create some sample expressions, and analyse their structure.  There is for example a "Sum" class.  But to do that you need to learn some basics about how `sympy` expressions are constructed.  In other words, learn more about `sympy` basics that what you get from a tutorial.

Comment: OP, may I ask for what purpose you wish to generate random expressions? Thanks for any info.

Comment: @RobertDodier it's for a secret antimilitary anarchist project (an educational software :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following might help you get started:

```
from random import choice, randint
from sympy import FunctionClass, Add, Mul, cos, sin, binomial, arity, S

def args(n, atoms, funcs):
    a = funcs+atoms
    g = []
    for _ in range(n):
        ai = choice(a)
        if isinstance(ai, FunctionClass):
            g.append(ai(*args(arity(ai), atoms, funcs)))
        else:
            g.append(ai)
    return g

def expr(ops, atoms, funcs=()):
  types = [Add, Mul]
  atoms = tuple(atoms)
  while 1:
    e = S.Zero
    while e.count_ops() < ops:
        _ = choice(types)(*args(randint(1,3), atoms, funcs))
        e = choice(types)(e, _)
        if e is S.NaN: break
    else:
        return e

>>> [expr(5, (-1,0,1,x,y)) for do in range(2)]
[(x - 1)*(2*x + y + 2), x + y*(x + 4*y - 2) + y]
>>> expr(5, (-1,0,1,x,y), (cos, binomial))
x*y**2 + x + cos(1)
>>> expr(5, (-1,0,1,x,y), (cos, binomial))
(y + zoo*binomial(y, x) - 2)*(y + cos(1) + 1)
```

To generate rational expressions you could change make the 2nd `_` arg be `_**choice((1,-1))`.

Comment: OK it seems it is not as elementary as I hoped! I see I have to understand how to use *args

Comment: Almost every SymPy expression has a `.func` and `.args` property. So to build a random expression you have to pick a func (like Add or Mul) and give it args and rebuild like `func(*args)`, e.g. `Add(*[1,x])`. The routines above are just supplying randomly assembled expressions.

Comment: There was also some similar goals discussed in terms of Hypothesis [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/17190).